# Worker path is not fired error says 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ace-editor, worker

Reference doc:- https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Syntax-validation
I added createWorker method to the custom mode according to the above doc, and included the worker-example.js in the same file and called require("ace/config").set("workerPath", "ace/mode") in mode definition

Currently, the workerPath is not being fired, I'm seeing a "GET http://localhost:3000/ace/mode/worker-example.js 404 (Not Found)" error in the console.

Here is my custom code index.html.erb :

```
define('ace/mode/example-custom', [], function(require, exports, module) {
var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
var Tokenizer = require("ace/tokenizer").Tokenizer;
var ExampleHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/example_highlight_rules").ExampleHighlightRules;
var WorkerClient = require("ace/worker/worker_client").WorkerClient;
require("ace/config").set("workerPath", "ace/mode");

var Mode = function() {
this.HighlightRules = ExampleHighlightRules;
};
oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

(function() {
this.lineCommentStart = "--";
this.blockComment = {start: "->", end: "<-"};

this.createWorker = function(session) {
    var worker = new WorkerClient(["ace"], workerpath, "WorkerExample");
    worker.attachToDocument(session.getDocument());

    console.log("worker", worker);
    worker.on("errors", function(e) {
        session.setAnnotations(e.data);
    });

    worker.on("annotate", function(results) {
        session.setAnnotations(results.data);
    });
    worker.on("terminate", function() {
        session.clearAnnotations();
    });
    return worker;
};
define('ace/mode/worker-example', [], function(require, exports, module) {
var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
var Mirror = require("ace/worker/mirror").Mirror;

var WorkerExample = exports.WorkerExample = function(sender) {
Mirror.call(this, sender);
this.setTimeout(200);
};
oop.inherits(WorkerExample, Mirror);

(function() {
this.onUpdate = function() {
var lines = editor.session.doc.getAllLines();
var errors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
if (/[\w\d{(['"]/.test(lines[i])) {
alert("hello");
errors.push({
row: i,
column: lines[i].length,
text: "Missing Semicolon",
type: "error"
});
}
}
this.sender.emit("annotate", errors);
};
}).call(WorkerExample.prototype);
});
```

Comment: is `define('ace/mode/worker-example',` in the same file with mode? it should be in a separate file.

Comment: @auser I have tried worker-example in same file as well as in separate file. But it doesn't work for me. What is the correct workerPath I need to give here require("ace/config").set("workerPath", "ace/mode") in same file and separate file.